# Add a dollar symbol before all the column values coming from ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, servicenow

I have a few columns in which for one column I need to add '$' symbol before each value of that single column as shown in the below image.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BoRFr.png)

The columns are coming from below script.

```
<tbody>
          <tr ng-repeat="item in data.list track by item.sys_id">
            <td role="cell" class="pointer sp-list-cell" ng-class="{selected: item.selected}" ng-click="go(item.targetTable, item)" ng-repeat="field in ::data.fields_array" data-field="{{::field}}" data-th="{{::data.column_labels[field]}}"><span ng-if="$first" aria-label="${Open record}: {{::item[field].display_value}}" role="link" tabindex="0">{{::item[field].display_value | limitTo : item[field].limit}}{{::item[field].display_value.length > item[field].limit ? '...' : ''}}</span><span ng-if="!$first">{{::item[field].display_value | limitTo : item[field].limit}}{{::item[field].display_value.length > item[field].limit ? '...' : ''}}</span>
            </td>
            <td><a href="/sys_attachment.do?sys_id={{item.attachment_sys_id}}">{{item.attachment_name}}</a></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
```

Can you please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to modify the second column

```
<tbody>
<tr ng-repeat="item in data.list track by item.sys_id">
    <td role="cell" class="pointer sp-list-cell" ng-class="{selected: item.selected}" ng-click="go(item.targetTable, item)" ng-repeat="field in ::data.fields_array" data-field="{{::field}}" data-th="{{::data.column_labels[field]}}">
        <span ng-if="$first" aria-label="${Open record}: {{::item[field].display_value}}" role="link" tabindex="0">{{::item[field].display_value | limitTo : item[field].limit}}{{::item[field].display_value.length > item[field].limit ? '...' : ''}}</span>
        <span ng-if="!$first">
            <!-- Check if it is the specific column to modify -->
            <span ng-if="data.fields_array.indexOf(field) == 1">$</span>
            {{::item[field].display_value | limitTo : item[field].limit}}{{::item[field].display_value.length > item[field].limit ? '...' : ''}}
        </span>
    </td>
    <td><a href="/sys_attachment.do?sys_id={{item.attachment_sys_id}}">{{item.attachment_name}}</a></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can just add a '$' before the value.

```
<td><span>$ {{ someValue }}</span></td>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But how do I identify that particular column which is coming from ng-repeat